# Maximum file size of a flat data file?

Tags: php, filesize, flat-file

I use flat files on my website to store account information for my game. But now, gem collecting doesn't work anymore. The filesize of the "accounts.ini" file is 218,750 bytes and the bottom of it looks like this:

```
[117157336030342728342]
GEMS = 7
[112725622837339591876]
GEMS = "1 4"4"
```

As you can see, the last line is wrong for some reason. What is causing this? Did I hit the filesize limit?

**EDIT:** Well, I should have tried it before, but I edited the last line to normal and it started working again. But you're right, I should use a database for such things. I've tried using a database before, but I didn't like it back then, but I guess that's not a good reason not to use it. I was just told that I won't be able to reach the "php.ini" file. I don't think I can find it either. Anyways, I'll switch to a database now, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Well, my first question: Why don't you use a database?

Comment: What settings do you have in your php.ini for `php_value memory_limit`? I agreed with @YUNOWORK that you should consider using a database for this instead.

Comment: Looks like a code bug or that the GEM value could have been injected by a user. The file size is not large and doesn't look like a typical limit.

Comment: As per your edit: phpinfo() in a single page would give you the actual configuration (ini_set if allowed on your server let you change some values)